# Is there a way to specify a range for the UPPER limit of an axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on an interactive `ggplot` graph of covid cases using shiny apps. Users are able to select the region to view new cases. Currently, my y-axis adjusts depending on the number of cases in the region selected by the user.

I would like for the y-axis lower limit to always be 0, but for the *upper* limit of the y-axis to start at least 50 and expand depending on the data selected. Otherwise, small towns with a handful of cases have really tall bars which is undesirable. I get that I can use the below to set hard upper and lower limits.

`scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,50))`

But I need something a little more sophisticated, like

`scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,50-400))`

Does this feature exist? Thanks.

Comment: You will have to manually calculate the upper limit from your data set.

Comment: No you don't, you can use functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can set the limits of a scale to a function that returns the correct limits. It takes the natural data limits as inputs and should return a length 2 numeric vector.

A few demonstrations:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.2

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1:5, 1:5),
  y = c(1:5, seq(100, 500, by = 100)),
  group = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 5)
)

yscale <- scale_y_continuous(
  limits = function(x){c(0, max(50, x[2]))}
)


base <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y))

base + geom_point(data = subset(df, group == "A")) +
  yscale
```

[image]

```r
base + geom_point() +
  yscale
```

[image]

```r
base + geom_point() +
  yscale +
  facet_wrap(~ group, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Why not define in your `renderPlot()` function an upper limit that is the maximum of either `50` or `max(y_value)`?  Something like this should work, where `plot_function()` is your `renderPlot()` function in the app:

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- 1:100

df1 <- data.frame(x,y=sample(1:10, 100, replace=TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(x,y=sample(1:500, 100, replace=TRUE))

plot_function <- function(d) {
  upper_lim <- max(c(50, max(d$y)))
  p <- ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
    ylim(0,upper_lim) +
    ggtitle(deparse(substitute(d)))  # prints name of d object
  print(p)
}
```

Compare the plots when `plot_function()` is sent `df1` vs `df2` (using `cowplot` for clarity):

```
library(cowplot)
p1 <- plot_function(df1)
p2 <- plot_function(df2)
plot_grid(p1,p2)
```

[image]

#### What should the renderPlot() function look like?

I started to answer your comment with another comment, but thought it's best to post an edit to the answer.  Considering you reference that you have a function to return your plot dataframe (called `plotdata()`), here's what I would try.  Note that `upper_lim` needs to be defined in the function and then used for the `ggplot()` call.  I find it's easiest in `renderPlot()` to store the plot to a variable, then `print()` that plot:

```
output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
  upper_lim <- max(c(50, max(plotdata()$y)))
  p <- ggplot(...) + ylim(0, upper_lim)
  print(p)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a good approach. Bear with me -- I'm new to R. I've arranged the code this way, but am getting an "object 'upper_lim' not found".   I realize I've probably made a rookie syntax error so any help is appreciated.                
   output$newplot <- renderPlot({
    function(d) {
      upper_lim <- max(c(50, max(d$y)))
    }
    
    ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x=date, y=newcases2, fill = Locality)) + 
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, upper_lim)) + ....

Comment: See the edit to the question for my suggestion.  Let me know if it works or if you had to make some changes and I'll re-edit if there's an adjustment.

Comment: So the app runs now with your revisions except that it just imposes an upper limit of 50, regardless of the data. If there are days that have more than 50 cases, it just omits that data instead of upping the upper limit. Any other thoughts are much appreciated.   output$newplot <- renderPlot({
    
      upper_lim <- max(c(30, max(plotdata()$y)))
    
    p <- ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x=date, y=newcases2, fill = Locality)) + 
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, upper_lim)) +

Comment: Likely that means `plotdata()$y` is not returning the vector of numbers in that column.  I'm not sure how your `plotdata()` function works, and you will want to make sure it's a reactive function in this case.  This will ensure the data is loaded before the `ggplot()` call in order to set `upper_lim`.  You do have a column called `y` in the returning dataset, correct?

Comment: Yes, plotdata() is a reactive function that selects a region based on user input. However, I did not have a column y -- i had thought that your $y was referencing the axis rather than a column. I put in the relevant data column, which is "newcases2", but now I'm back at square one -- it adjusts the y axis for max values and won't hold to a min of 50: output$newplot <- renderPlot({upper_lim <- max(c(30, max(plotdata()$newcases2)))